# Find maximum and group to dataset?

Tags: pandas, numpy, lambda, group-by, max

[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtT5v.png)

> Here is my pandas Dataframe I'm working with above.. shape is (1049,3) 
>   I'm a beginner and I'm having some difficulty trying to achieve my goal of answering
>   "which genre is popular from year to year"
>
> > 1) release_year = 1960 to 2015 and includes multiple same years (integers)
> >     2) genre = 20 types (objects) 
> >     3) no missing values
>
> I've tried this, but I'm getting an error saying I can't use irow

```
    genre.groupby('release_year').apply(lambda genre:genre.irow(genre.value.argmax()))
```

> Ultimately I want something that looks like this...(x,y)

```
                  popular_genre      
    release_year    
      1960          Drama
      1961          Comedy
      1962          Action
       .
       .
      2015         Science Fiction
```

> So I can plot it using histogram or line. I may have to divide up the years by decades if it's too ugly to graph with so many x-values.
>
> My original plan is to 1st find genre with the highest count from each year and then put it into the Dataframe or make a new one
>
> Or am I thinking too much and is there a way bypass this by just plotting?

Thank you all so much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby twice and get the genre with largest count.

```
(
    df.groupby(by=['release_year'])
    .apply(lambda x: x.groupby('popular_genre')['count']
                      .sum().nlargest(1))
)
```

If popular_genre is unique for each year, you can also do:

```
(
    df.groupby(by='release_year', as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('count').tail(1))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! There is no 'popular_gene' column  (I need to somehow plot most popular genre per year from 1960-2015). I'm thinking of going with histogram.  I was wondering if I understand the code correctly. So the df groups by 'release_year' column without setting it as an index. So from there we have an object, so we need to add a function so we use .apply with the accompanying function lambda. So then the function lambda does is sort_values (and only within 'release_year'). **Then what is tail(1) doing? Is it because it needs at least one count? Thank you!**